# Python ConfigParser Invalid Syntax

Tags: python

I'm using the following code to read a config file:

```
def get_config():
    c = configparser.ConfigParser()
    c.read("config.cfg")
    return c.options("Server")
```

The file looks like this:

```
[Server]
port = 9012
workspace = doc/
```

But I get the following error:

```
  File "config.cfg", line 3
    workspace = doc/
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to run the configuration file as if it were a Python script.  Here's one way to reproduce your error:

```
C:\Users\Luke\StackOverflow>python config.cfg
  File "config.cfg", line 3
    workspace = doc/
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```